# Conjunction 'therefore' and 'but'

Tags: conjunctions

1.He was so angry, but he couldn't say anything .
2. He was so angry, therefore he couldn't say anything. Which one I must choose?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, People. We love people. And People. But to answer your question, we need a little more information. Please edit your question to include more information. For example, Why do you have this question? Is it from homework, for example? Do you know what *therefore* means, and what *but* means? Which answer do you think might be correct, and why?

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, but they have different meanings.

With "but", it means that the second part contradicts the first part in some way. Here it would mean that, normally, angry people do say a lot, but for some reason he was unable to say anything this time. The reason is missing though and would have to come from extra context. For example, if he was in a library and had to be quiet.

With "therefore", it means that anger causes him to be unable to talk. The second part logically follows from the first part. (Also, the punctuation is technically incorrect since this is a comma splice. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/106517/272) for more info.)

---

Going beyond the original question:

In both cases, you are using "so" as a simple adverb modifying "angry", but a more natural use of "so" here is like this, without any commas:

> He was so angry that he couldn't say anything.

This assumes that the meaning should be like the one with "therefore," not like the one with "but."

Answer (score 0):

> **He was so  angry,   but  he  could  not say thing**
>
> **He was  so  angry . Therefore, he could  not  say anything**

We  use  the  conjunction but to  show  the contrast.

We  use therefore in the meaning of  for  that reason.

in  the  two sentences your  second  seems  to  be  correct  because  his   anger  made  him not  to  speak.

But

Inspite of  his anger  he  could  not  say thing is possible.

Then both  the  sentences  are  correct  and  possible.