# Is "therefore" in the right place in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I wrote a sentence, and I am confused about the word 'therefore', if 'therefore' in a right place. If this sentence has another error, please point out. Thank you.
Here is the sentence:

> Some people have talent skills, these people therefore learn some things far faster than others.

Comment: "Talent skills" doesn't make sense, because *talent* and *skill* mean essentially the same thing.  Use one word or the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to begin a sentence with "Therefore"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106512/when-to-begin-a-sentence-with-therefore) And more generally, [Confusion over the position of an adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/confusion-over-the-position-of-an-adverb)

Comment: I'd say *Some people are naturally/innately talented/gifted and therefore they learn ([some] things) faster (than others).* But I don't know what you want to say. It's a very general statement and seems somewhat obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Placement of "therefore" can sometimes be a choice, for example:

- I feel unwell, therefore I am going home.
- I feel unwell, I am therefore going home.

However, 'therefore' can be understood to mean '*it follows that*', so you must ensure it is placed between the *reason and the *consequence* in your statement. In your example, you seem to be making a link between *existing skills* and *ability to learn new skills*. You have quite a lot of superfluous language in your sentence which makes that link unclear. For example, you refer to "some people" and then "these people" when I perceive you mean the same people. "Talent skills" doesn't make sense, as a skill is learned and a talent is often believed to be inherent. You should use one or the other.

You would be better to say something like:

> Some people are naturally talented and therefore learn things faster than others.